# Magento Connect vs Magento Marketplace

Tags: magento2, magento-1, magento-connect, magento-connect-manager, marketplace

So the official Magento marketplace is out.

I was wondering what does that imply for developers ?

- do developers have to move all their extensions to Magento marketplace (when will Magento Connect be shutted down?)
- should developers keep their extensions on both platforms before Magento Connect is shutted down?
- will customers still be able to install extensions from the marketplace via the Magento Connect Manager ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Currently the Marketplace is Magento 2-only, and Connect is Magento 1-only. Later this year Magento 1 support will be added to the Marketplace (on a temporary basis, I think), at which point vendors will be engaged to migrate their listings across. Once that is done, Connect will go away entirely. The exact timeline and migration process is yet to be announced.
2. Yes, there's no harm to keeping extensions on both (although, as noted, currently there should not be any overlap in listings--one is M1, the other is M2).
3. As noted in #1, currently the Marketplace is M2-only, so this is not relevant.  I would expect once Magento 1 extensions are supported on the new Marketplace, that will include support for the existing Magento 1 Connect Manager.

Source: Announcements and session on the Marketplace at Magento Imagine 2016.

Answer (score 0):

The new Magento Connect Market place does not seem to sort as well as the left side bar might indicate and I found it hard to sort out what I needed for extensions, And forget about Magento 1.9.x extensions (very few) and many of the ones found ended up being M2 extensions anyway. 
However some are now on github, "magento 1.9", found 753 repository results [[https://github.com/search?q=magento+1.9&type=Repositories]](https://github.com/search?q=magento%201.9&type=Repositories)

Email me if you need some older ones for Magento 1.6.x as I have about 40 of these cached on my local machine.
 If you know the URL one of my favorite links was [Direct Download Magento Extension Without Pear](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php?ext=http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Dewatasoft_ChangeAttributeSet) as I could capture the whole Package without 'Magento Connect' to my HDD.

One might ask Why M1? and the answer is I need to reconstruct my old website as, somewhere around 1.6.x, a Magento upgrade seem to start mangling the database.
Also too many of the setup scripts seem to no longer have the `IF EXISTS DROP DATABASE` included for the resource changes. So I want something that works first Since I got hurt and I was off line so long